# SourceTree Push count working differently and I don't know why

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

How the repositories are setup:

- Local server has the main repository, the one that all our developers push changes to
- Online repository with BitBucket that is rarely needs updated so I only push to that every now and then

For a long time, on my repository SourceTree would keep count of the number of commits I had to push to the server. That number was shown at the top in the push icon.

Now, the number of commits I have to push is always relative to the online repository. I don't why it changed, or how. This number means a lot less to me and I would prefer to see how many commits I to push to our local server.

When I click "Push", the default repository is the local server. The online repository is the only other option. (Whenever I do a push the push works as expected for either local or online.)

Overall this is a pretty minor problem. But I would like to know why this has changed and how to change it back.

Edit: Just to clarify the branch that I am on has always been the same, as are the branches that I push to.

Comment: Any reason for the -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [the answer to my problem](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/172242/how-to-setup-default-push-branch), it had to do with which branch was getting tracked.

For anyone who has this problem the solution was to: "Right-click your local branch in the sidebar on the left, then select Track Remote Branch, and then the remote branch you want it to track."

Comment: your link is broken btw.